# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - push service error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hapi.js, web-push

I am trying to send push notifications to mobile users when a button is clicked. I can receive such notifications on the desktop, but when I use chrome emulator on the mobile device, I get "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Registration failed - push service error". The button I'm talking about triggers the service worker registration and push subscription and making a post request to node/hapi server that triggers web-push library to send the notification notification.

Below is the function that triggers the post request:

```
$scope.sendNotification = async function run() {
            console.log('Registering service worker');
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.
            register('/sw.js', { scope: '/' });
            console.log('Registered service worker');

            registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
                .then(function(subscription) {
                    if (subscription) {
                        return subscription.unsubscribe();
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log('Error unsubscribing', error);
                })
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('User is unsubscribed');
                    isSubscribed = false;
                });

            console.log('Registering push');
            let subs = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                //The `urlBase64ToUint8Array()` function is the same as in
                // https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push#using-vapid-key-for-applicationserverkey
                applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
                //gcm_sender_id: "681339210596"
            });

            let subJSObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subs));
            let p256dh = subJSObject.keys.p256dh;
            let auth = subJSObject.keys.auth;

            console.log(subs.endpoint);

            console.log('Registered push');

            console.log('Sending push');
            let subscription = {
                endpoint: subs.endpoint,
                keys: {
                    p256dh: p256dh,
                    auth: auth
                }
            };

            await fetch('/pushNotification', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({subscription: subscription}),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            }); 
            console.log('Sent push');
        }




//Excerpt of the server...
const publicVapidKey = 'BJqx_xc-m75vN7aO_mUE2vfaKCh1j5YBQfWT0f2CO0ZDJOdsqayjaHjagbCbmj9jggGEGyTtcim7VrpbTckTnsU';
const privateVapidKey = 'HyYeJXmgnrL_3t8RGH32HfGcRpsWyBFM0YzdoO_zSZ8';

webPush.setVapidDetails('mailto:cj.ugwuanyi@gmail.com', publicVapidKey, privateVapidKey);

server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/pushNotification',
    handler: async (request, h) => {

        const subscription = request.payload.subscription;
        const payload = JSON.stringify({title: 'Update!', body: 'This is a fresh update from the server!'});

        return webPush.sendNotification(subscription, payload).then(function(response) {
            console.log('Response: ', response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error)
            return error;
        })  
}
})
```

//Now the app manifest.

```
{
  "name": "PwaApp",
  "short_name": "PwaApp",
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000",
  "background_color": "#000",
  "description": "A sample PWA powered app!",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/icon.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "images/review.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "gcm_sender_id": "681339210596",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true
}
```

Please forgive me if the question is too long. This is my first question here.

Comment: What browser are you using?